# Wireless interface not detected on computer (but is detected on install media)

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

Recently, after using Arch Linux for a month without many problems, `ip link` stopped showing my wireless interface (which was `wlp2s0`). I rebooted and all -- no magic fix. So I booted from my installation media. `ip link` on the install media lists a wireless interface (`wlan0`), and connecting to my network with `wifi-menu` doesn't error. But pinging google.com still responds with `temporary failure in name resolution`.

Now here's the strange part: If I `arch-chroot` into my machine from the media (after `wifi-menu` from the media), without using `wifi-menu` after chrooting, then it lets me connect to the internet properly.

Here are some of commands' output:

`lspci -nnk` (not full output, if you need more let me know)

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 11)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:108e]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:2110]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: wilwifi
```

`$ ip link` (on host computer)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:ee:cb:6c:52:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`lsmod` at http://ix.io/2bvM

```
Module                  Size  Used by
vboxdrv               528384  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      32768  1 intel_rapl_msr
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
kvm_intel             311296  0
kvm                   802816  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    94208  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
btusb                  65536  0
iwlmvm                454656  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
mousedev               24576  0
mei_hdcp               24576  0
mac80211             1007616  1 iwlmvm
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                32768  1 btusb
ums_realtek            24576  0
bluetooth             675840  5 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,btusb
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
i915                 2449408  2
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
nls_cp437              20480  1
iwlwifi               405504  1 iwlmvm
joydev                 28672  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
hid_logitech_hidpp     45056  0
vfat                   24576  1
input_leds             16384  0
cryptd                 24576  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
fat                    86016  1 vfat
intel_cstate           16384  0
intel_uncore          147456  0
r8169                  94208  0
cfg80211              860160  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        237568  1 i915
snd_hda_intel          57344  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
rfkill                 28672  3 bluetooth,cfg80211
drm                   557056  3 drm_kms_helper,i915
realtek                20480  0
psmouse               180224  0
snd_hda_codec         163840  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
pcspkr                 16384  0
libphy                114688  2 r8169,realtek
snd_hda_core          106496  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               139264  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
intel_gtt              24576  1 i915
agpgart                53248  2 intel_gtt,drm
snd_timer              40960  1 snd_pcm
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
wmi                    36864  2 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof
snd                   114688  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
soundcore              16384  1 snd
evdev                  24576  7
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 45056  1
mei                   122880  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
mac_hid                16384  0
tpm_crb                20480  0
tpm_tis                16384  0
tpm_tis_core           32768  1 tpm_tis
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
tpm                    73728  3 tpm_tis,tpm_crb,tpm_tis_core
rng_core               16384  1 tpm
i2c_i801               36864  0
sg                     40960  0
ip_tables              36864  0
x_tables               53248  1 ip_tables
ext4                  786432  1
crc32c_generic         16384  0
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
hid_logitech_dj        28672  0
jbd2                  135168  1 ext4
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 65536  1 hid_logitech_dj
hid                   147456  4 usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
sr_mod                 28672  0
cdrom                  77824  1 sr_mod
sd_mod                 57344  4
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            77824  2 uas,ums_realtek
serio_raw              20480  0
atkbd                  36864  0
libps2                 20480  2 atkbd,psmouse
ahci                   40960  3
libahci                45056  1 ahci
libata                290816  2 libahci,ahci
xhci_pci               20480  0
crc32c_intel           24576  2
xhci_hcd              282624  1 xhci_pci
scsi_mod              258048  6 sd_mod,usb_storage,uas,libata,sg,sr_mod
i8042                  32768  0
serio                  28672  6 serio_raw,atkbd,psmouse,i8042
```

`dmesg | grep iwlwifi` at http://ix.io/2bvN

```
[    7.560427] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.599395] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.163394017.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.782429] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3168, REV=0x220
[    7.800962] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Can't parse phy_sku in B0, empty sections
[    7.800964] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to read NVM: -61
[    7.800966] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[    7.802130] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    7.802132] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[    7.802133] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.163394017.0
[    7.802134] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[    7.802135] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    7.802136] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    7.802137] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0004171E | branchlink2
[    7.802138] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000446B2 | interruptlink1
[    7.802139] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000446B2 | interruptlink2
[    7.802140] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[    7.802141] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
[    7.802141] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x07030000 | data3
[    7.802142] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    7.802143] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000150B | tsf low
[    7.802144] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    7.802145] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    7.802146] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000150B | time gp2
[    7.802147] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000009 | uCode revision type
[    7.802148] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001D | uCode version major
[    7.802148] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x09BD31E1 | uCode version minor
[    7.802149] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000220 | hw version
[    7.802150] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00C89200 | board version
[    7.802151] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00110188 | hcmd
[    7.802152] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00022000 | isr0
[    7.802153] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    7.802154] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000002 | isr2
[    7.802155] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x004000C0 | isr3
[    7.802156] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    7.802156] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00110188 | last cmd Id
[    7.802157] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[    7.802158] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00004A9B | l2p_control
[    7.802159] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    7.802160] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    7.802161] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    7.802162] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000007 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    7.802162] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x07100855 | timestamp
[    7.802163] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00341018 | flow_handler
[    7.802171] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    7.802176] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    7.802181] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    7.802186] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    7.802192] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    7.802197] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    7.802202] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    7.802207] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    7.802212] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    7.802217] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    7.802222] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    7.802227] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    7.802232] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    7.802237] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    7.814368] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -61
```

`dmesg | grep -i firmware` at http://ix.io/2bvL.

```
[    0.365386] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    7.545161] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    7.599395] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.163394017.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.666717] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    7.802133] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.163394017.0
[    7.802237] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    7.807997] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-22.50.19.14.f.bseq
[    8.092357] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I did somehow, but it was so long ago that I can't remember. Maybe a kernel upgrade did the trick. In any case I've gotten a little more experienced since then and haven't had any more problems :)